# Confirmation sweet alert with condition

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I'am use sweeet alert with type input text to handle confirmation in my program. This is my js code,

```
$(document).on('click', '.tl_skripsi', function(){  
                    var id          = $(this).attr("id"); //ID mjudul
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: "Anda yakin tidak lulus?",
                        text: "",
                        input: 'text',
                        inputPlaceholder: "Ketik 'TIDAK LULUS'",
                        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
                        confirmButtonText: "Tidak Lulus",
                        closeOnConfirm: false,
                        cancelButtonText: "Batal",
                        showCancelButton: true,
                    }).then(result => {
                            var konfirmasi = swal.getInput();
                            if (konfirmasi === "TIDAK LULUS") {
                                  $.ajax({
                                   url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>prodi/#',
                                   type: 'POST',
                                   data: {id: id},
                                   error: function() {
                                      alert('Something is wrong');
                                   },
                                   success: function(data) {
                                        window.location.href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>prodi/redirect_tl_skripsi";
                                   }
                                  });
                            } else {
                                toastr.error(konfirmasi);
                            }
                    })
                });
```

My problem is condition always return **false** even though I have type **TIDAK LULUS**.

> Note: value `konfirmasi` is captured

Comment: Are you sure to use the right value as result ? Maybe you can try `var konfirmasi = result`. And also add some logs to debug `console.log(konfirmasi)`

Comment: sure, because toastr.error(konfirmasi) return my input value

Comment: but wait, when i change with `console log`, my return is `<input class="swal2-input" style="display: flex;" placeholder="Ketik 'TIDAK LULUS'" type="text">`

Comment: Thank's for your information to debug with `console.log(konfirmasi)`, now  my problem has been clear,